MAUI DropDown/Select
How do I create a similar DropDown/Select in MAUI. Any possible examples? I just need to make a tooltip for data validation so that it is displayed on top of all elements of type like in HTML position:absolute;. But I can't find anything like that anywhere. I only understand that this should be done through the own Controls
enter image description here enter image description here
I use third-party Controls. And I don't understand how they made them. I would like a small sample, or a link on how to do it
Any information and examples

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Depending on the specific needs, we have various ways to achieve DropDown list.
For example, we can create a ComboBox class with the Listview and the Entry.
Please refer to the following code:
public class ComboBox : StackLayout
    {
        private Entry _entry;
        private ListView _listView;
        private bool _supressFiltering;
        private bool _supressSelectedItemFiltering;
        //Bindable properties
        public static readonly BindableProperty ListViewHeightRequestProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ListViewHeightRequest), typeof(double), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.HeightRequest = (double)newVal;
        });
        public double ListViewHeightRequest
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ListViewHeightRequestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ListViewHeightRequestProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty EntryBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._entry.BackgroundColor = (Color)newVal;
        });
        public Color EntryBackgroundColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(EntryBackgroundColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EntryBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty EntryFontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryFontSize), typeof(double), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._entry.FontSize = (double)newVal;
        });
        [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
        public double EntryFontSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(EntryFontSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EntryFontSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)newVal;
        });
        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedItem), typeof(object), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.SelectedItem = newVal;
        });
        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }
        public static new readonly BindableProperty VisualProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Visual), typeof(IVisual), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: new DefaultVisual(), propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.Visual = (IVisual)newVal;
            comboBox._entry.Visual = (IVisual)newVal;
        });
        public new IVisual Visual
        {
            get { return (IVisual)GetValue(VisualProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VisualProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Placeholder), typeof(string), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: "", propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._entry.Placeholder = (string)newVal;
        });
        public string Placeholder
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: "", propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._entry.Text = (string)newVal;
        });
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldVal, newVal) => {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox)bindable;
            comboBox._listView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)newVal;
        });
        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty EntryDisplayPathProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryDisplayPath), typeof(string), typeof(ComboBox), defaultValue: "");
        public string EntryDisplayPath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(EntryDisplayPathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EntryDisplayPathProperty, value); }
        }
        public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> SelectedItemChanged;
        protected virtual void OnSelectedItemChanged(SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> handler = SelectedItemChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        public event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged;
        protected virtual void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> handler = TextChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        public ComboBox()
        {
            //Entry used for filtering list view
            _entry = new Entry();
            _entry.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            _entry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.None);
            _entry.Focused += (sender, args) => _listView.IsVisible = true;
            _entry.Unfocused += (sender, args) => _listView.IsVisible = false;
            //Text changed event, bring it back to the surface
            _entry.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (_supressFiltering)
                    return;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.NewTextValue))
                {
                    _supressSelectedItemFiltering = true;
                    _listView.SelectedItem = null;
                    _supressSelectedItemFiltering = false;
                }
                _listView.IsVisible = true;
                OnTextChanged(args);
            };
            //List view - used to display search options
            _listView = new ListView();
            _listView.IsVisible = false;
            _listView.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.ListView.SetSeparatorStyle(_listView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.SeparatorStyle.FullWidth);
            _listView.HeightRequest = 100;
            _listView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
            _listView.SetBinding(ListView.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding(nameof(ComboBox.SelectedItem), source: this));
            //Item selected event, surface it back to the top
            _listView.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (!_supressSelectedItemFiltering)
                {
                    _supressFiltering = true;
                    var selectedItem = args.SelectedItem;
                    _entry.Text = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(EntryDisplayPath) && selectedItem != null ? selectedItem.GetType().GetProperty(EntryDisplayPath).GetValue(selectedItem, null).ToString() : selectedItem?.ToString();
                    _supressFiltering = false;
                    _listView.IsVisible = false;
                    OnSelectedItemChanged(args);
                    _entry.Unfocus();
                }
            };
            //Add bottom border
            var boxView = new BoxView();
            boxView.HeightRequest = 1;
            boxView.Color = Colors.Black;
            boxView.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            boxView.SetBinding(BoxView.IsVisibleProperty, new Binding(nameof(ListView.IsVisible), source: _listView));
            Children.Add(_entry);
            Children.Add(_listView);
            Children.Add(boxView);
           
        }
        public new bool Focus()
        {
            return _entry.Focus();
        }
        public new void Unfocus()
        {
            _entry.Unfocus();
        }
    }

Then you can  set the itemsource in the code behind:
combobox.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5","item6" };

And use it in the xaml:
<local:ComboBox x:Name="combobox"  SelectedItemChanged="combobox_SelectedItemChanged"/>


Sorry. I tried what you suggested. It looks like what I need, but it doesn't render on top of the rest of the controls, it just pushes them to the bottom. And I need to understand how to render on top of others as pop-ups, as if it were Select in Html/css
